# Spring mvc работа с изображениями

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Здравствуйте, делаю небольшое веб-приложение на Spring. Нужна возможность хранить изображения отправленные из формы на сервер. Как я понял самый оптимальный вариант хранить в файловой системе.

В jsp достаю изображения данным образом

servlet-context.xml
 `<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>`

ad.jsp
   `<img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/${ad.id}.jpg"/>"/>`

Сохраняю его так:
`File file = 
    new File( "/home/max/IdeaProjects/WebAppTest/src/main/webapp/resources/images/" + image + ".jpg");`

и всё хорошо, они там сохраняются,сразу же после отправки из формы.
но, когда я во время работы приложения добавляю новое изображение, оно сохраняется, но когда я захожу на страницу где оно должно было отобразиться, его там нет, ошибка загрузки(просто значок картинки показывается). Но стоит мне перезапустить приложение, оно будет показывать страницы со старыми изображениями, сохраненными в предыдущие сеансы работы, но опять же при создании новых будет так же не работать, пока не перезапущу. А у меня сервис типо подачи обьявлений, поэтому там такое недопустимо.

Comment: лучше не сохранять в архиве проекта, а сделать отдельное хранилище.

Comment: а можно пример?

Comment: Если мне память не изменяет, то сервер не поднимается выше рабочей директории. Ты делаешь папку в пределах веб приложения, а надо на уровне сервера сохраняться.